# Android: LED doesn't turn on/off

Tags: android, camera, widget, led

I'm trying to write a little Android widget with a button that turns the camera flashlight on/off. I know, there a thousands of it out there, but I want to learn Android (and little steps seem to be the best way).

Now I've read the official documentation, some free tutorials on the web and searched here on stackoverflow for it. So far I don't get any errors, LogCat says everything works as desired. But when I'm testing the app on my Galaxy Nexus, the switch turns on/off as it should but cams LED doesn't turn on/off.

Here is my code (only the parts where the LED is actually turned on/off):

```
if (isLightOn) {
    Log.d("receiver", "flashlight is on, disabling it");
    if (camera != null) {
        param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        isLightOn = false;                     
    }
} else {                                 
    Log.d("receiver", "flashlight is off, enabling it");
    camera = Camera.open();

    if(camera == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Set the torch flash mode                     
        param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        try {
            camera.setParameters(param);                   
            isLightOn = true;                                                      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_flash, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work as intended?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Did you add this permission to your manifest?

Comment: you also lack `camera = Camera.open();` you might also need `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` too in the Manifest.

Comment: Permissions are set and camera = Camera.open() is some lines above the code I posted

Comment: I meant camera = Camera.open() inside the if() and the else() conditions, you only have it inside the else.

Comment: I didn't realize that. The code is very much copy pasted from another question on here, where the guy who asked the question found a solution by himself. I now rearranged the code and made it more readable.

I now do camera = Camera.open() before going down the if() statements. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In general take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-turn-onoff-camera-ledflashlight-in-android/). It is correctly explained.

EDIT:

What;s on the link:

1. Turn on

   camera = Camera.open();
   Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
   p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
   camera.setParameters(p);
   camera.startPreview();
2. Turn off

   camera = Camera.open();
   Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
   p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
   camera.setParameters(p);
   camera.stopPreview();

And, put following permission on AndroidManifest.xml.

P.S This project is developed in Eclipse 3.7, and tested with Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 2.3.3).

1. Android Layout
   A button only.

File : res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFlashlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Torch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2. Activity
   Read the code, a button to turn on / off the flashlight, it should be self-explanatory.

   ```
   package com.mkyong.android;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.hardware.Camera;
   import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;

   public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity {

   //flag to detect flash is on or off
   private boolean isLighOn = false;

   private Camera camera;

   private Button button;

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();

       if (camera != null) {
           camera.release();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);

       Context context = this;
       PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

       // if device support camera?
       if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
           Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
           return;
       }

       camera = Camera.open();
       final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

               if (isLighOn) {

                   Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                   p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                   camera.setParameters(p);
                   camera.stopPreview();
                   isLighOn = false;

               } else {

                   Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");

                   p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                   camera.setParameters(p);
                   camera.startPreview();
                   isLighOn = true;

               }

           }
       });

   }
   }
   ```
3. Android Permission
   Assign CAMERA permission.

File : AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mkyong.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".FlashLightActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please add relevant parts of the link to the answer. Links may go bad.

Comment: Instead of a widget, I tried a simple with a simple button and using the code you linked to. But even that simple code doesn't work. No error, no exception - but still no flash.

Comment: Then try debugging it, I'm left with no ideas so far .. :(

Comment: I just downloaded the source from the link you posted, but this code doesn't work either. Just to let you know =)

Comment: Do you have any clue why? I used it once and it worked .. What might be the reason .. i got interested in this ..